# Multiple duplicate rows with only one column that is different. How do I combine those columns into the same row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a table that has a column "owners" with multiple users and when I create the table anything that has multiple owners will be two or more rows. I am trying to have the one column have the owners separated by commas and not be in different rows

I have tried to select distinct and other things but I am very new to sql

''`'select distinct s.id id, p.name project, u.name owners, s.story_type, s.name, e.name epic, s.loaded_at'''`

Actual results are two rows with every value the exact same except for the owners column that has two different values

The expected results would be one row with both owners in one column

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the **string_agg** function (which has been a feature of all Postgresql versions since 9.0) to turn multiple rows into a comma separated string:

```
SELECT  
  s.id id, p.name project, 
  STRING_AGG(u.name, ',') owners, 
  s.story_type, s.name, e.name epic, s.loaded_at  
FROM <...> -- replace with actual FROM and JOIN clauses
JOIN <...>
GROUP BY s.id, p.name, s.story_type, s.name, e.name, s.loaded_at
```

You must **not** include the `u.name` column in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy for you to insert all your data in the temp table #yourtable.
Then you can use "FOR XML PATH" to concatenate multiple rows together:

```
select distinct project_name,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + owner_name
     from #yourtable p1
     where p.[project_name] = p1.[project_name]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,2,'') owners
from #yourtable p;
```